# Highcharts tooltips for each series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use highstock with multiple series. Tooltip in his default behavior is displayed common for every series. But i need separated tooltips for each series, which is displayed on hover

Comment: Show us a code example of your problem.

Comment: I dont have code because i dont know how to realize this. I will try to explain what i really need. In standart situation we always have just one tooltip(this may have in content information about one or more than one series). But i need 3 tooltips at the same time for 3 series. Not one tooltip which includes information about 3 series.

Comment: What do you mean by 3 tooltips at the same time? If you mean separate boxes - then look at the split option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.tooltip.split

Comment: Thanks tooltip.split resolved problem. But now i have problems with styling all of this tooltips.